# dynamically refer to table name in Excel VLOOKUP formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Below I have a lookup table called `my_table`. I use `VLOOKUP` (see formula) to extract the *description* column based on the *name* info in the small example below (green font). However, I want dynamically refer to `my_table` using the name in cell `C8` (colored red). Hence, I want to replace the table name in the formula with a reference to the value in cell `C8`.

**How can I do that?**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `INDIRECT`.

E.g. something like:

```
= VLOOKUP(A11;INDIRECT(C8&"[[name]:[description]]");2;0)
```

Comment: nice, much simpler than I expected. Thanks